# Laravel eloquent grabbing results between two days

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model for which I have a database field called `day`. This is a unique field and it can contain a day like `monday`, `tuesday`, and so on. So `monday` can only be used once, etc. The value is literally stored as a string.

Now I am trying to display only upcoming x results, for example, only the results from the next 3 days. Which means, I want to display the result of today, tomorrow and the day after tomorrow. I have been trying like below:

```
Model::where('day', '>=', Carbon::now())
     ->where('day', '<', Carbon::now()->addDays(3))
     ->get();
```

But this does not give me any results. I want to prevent having to change the field to a date field, for now. But I was wondering if there is any way to achieve what I am looking for with a simple eloquent query.

Comment: You should probably give an id to your table, working with ids is much easier.

Comment: You can't compare a datetime to a string with the name of the weekday in an SQL query out of the box. Is it not better to store it as a date, this allows you to utilize a bunch of both Laravel and MySQL features. Store data as the datatype they represent. Is there a particular reason why you don't want to store it as a date?

Comment: And adding to that, how can you know if the `friday` value is this Friday, or a Friday in January?

Comment: My table has ids as well but that will not help me with my question. I just really wanted to know if it was even possible to do this really, just trying to learn. The reason I made it as it is now is because I want to update the values every week. And the friday will always be the next friday, not any other friday. So working with a date field means I have to make some edits. But I will re-think how to implement what I want and make the necessary changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the day is unique you can get the next three days and select their results:

```php
$today=Carbon::now()->dayName;
$tomorrow=Carbon::tomorrow()->dayName;
$afterTomorrow=Carbon::tomorrow()->addDay()->dayName;

$acceptableDays=[$today,$tomorrow,$afterTomorrow];
Model::whereIn('day', $acceptableDays)
      ->get();
```

pay attention to letter case, `Carbon::now()->dayName;` will gave you the day name with first capital letter, you should convert it to match the way it stored in your db

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a solution I can work with. I will have to update it because the results can change, 3 was just an example but I will be able to fix it the way I need it, thanks a lot

Comment: you can use CarbonPeriod to get day names in better way